# meaning of Republic

Tags: meaning, etymology, prefixes

I've been thinking what might be the real meaning of the word `Republic`?

As far as I know the prefix `re-` gives the base word the meaning of `again`; as in `renew, replace, reclaim`.

I am wondering what kind of a meaning does it give to `re_public`?

Comment: Have you looked in the dictionary? It gives you the origin of a word. That might help. Guessing often is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the word can help to understand the meaning:

> republic (n.) c.1600, "state in which supreme power rests in the people via elected representatives," from Middle French république (15c.), from Latin *respublica* (ablative *republica*) "the common weal, a commonwealth, state, republic,**literally res publica** "public interest, the state," from *res* "affair, matter, thing" + *publica*, fem. of publicus "public" (see public (adj.)). Republic of letters attested from 1702.

[Source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=republic&searchmode=none): Etymonline